# Variance of truncated normal distribution

Tags: variance, truncated-normal-distribution, example

I am trying to calculate the variance of a truncated normal distribution, var(X | a < X < b), given the expected value and variance of the unbound variable X. I believe I found the corresponding formula on wikipedia (see picture below), but as a Psychologist I am not trained in mathematics and cannot read the formula.

Could somebody show me how to do the calculations for an exemplary case?
Let's say for example if a=0, b=1, var(X) = 0.5, E(X) = 0.5, then what is var(X | a < X < b)?

I would be super greatful for help.
All the Best,
ajj

[image: Formula according to wikipedia]

Comment: Are you using any language/calculator ?

Comment: I am using r. I could simulate the results of my question in r btw, but am looking for the numerical calculation. Simulation in r pseudo-code: for_loop{vector<-var(rtruncnorm(N, a, b,mean, var))} mean(vector) ~ var(x|a<x<b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in R you could do:

```
a <- 0
b <- 1
vr <- 0.5 
mu <- 0.5
alpha <- (a - mu)/sqrt(vr)
beta <- (b - mu)/sqrt(vr)
denom <- pnorm(beta) - pnorm(alpha)
vr * (1 - (beta*dnorm(beta) - alpha*dnorm(alpha))/denom - 
    ((dnorm(beta) - dnorm(alpha))/denom)^2)

[1] 0.07791413
```

You can compare this with simulated data:

```
set.seed(20)
var((x<-rnorm(3e6, mu,sqrt(vr)))[x>a&x<b])
[1] 0.07791103
```

Comment: There is a distinction between $a$ and $\alpha$, and between $b$ and $\beta$

Comment: Works well, super impressive. Thanks for the qick response! I am wondering if we could turn the question around: Which var(X) leads to var(X| a < X < b) = 0.5? But this would just be an add on, you already helped me a lot!